# How can I seal the lids on water collection barrels?

Tags: water, sealing, storage

I'm working on a rainwater collection system.

Due to space limitations, I have arranged the barrels in a 2x2 configuration (as in the picture)

Problem with this configuration is that I can't get a good seal on the lids, and the 2 barrels on top never fill up.

Any ideas to improve the seal?

[image]

Comment: The barrels may seal better if they are upside-down.

Comment: Sealed or not, stuff will grow in the water  so it will only be useful in the garden without treating.

Comment: Plastic barrels of 55 gallon size are commonly used to ship chemicals . The ones I have came with 2 small threaded(?) openings, should be fairly easy to seal . I have since cut off the tops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would fill the top 2 first as a pair then the overflow from those fills the bottom pair, then excess can be dealt with.

Of course one issue, if there is to be only one outlet is how to connect the top and bottom without a manual changeover. That can be done with a oneway valve so the top ones don’t drain into the bottom ones.

[image]

Edit: to deal with air being sucked in consider a second oneway valve above the outlet as shown, once the upper tanks no longer have water then the valve will close.

[image]

Once the top pair are full the fill to lower tanks takes the excess until the lower tanks are full then the overflow bottom left controls the final level.

The outlet is fed from the top tanks until empty, then the oneway valve allows water out to the outlet from the lower tanks. If you don't have the oneway valve the top tanks will just empty into the lower tanks.

This has the advantage that the lids are now just dustcovers and are easy to remove / replace for cleaning.

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for your suggestion. However I'm not sure I understand. The 4 barrels are connected and the outlet is at the bottom. The way I see it, no matter how I connect them the water will still escape..

Comment: @JuanCortines see my edit, simple with a oneway valve.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you :)

Comment: you could also have a float valve (like in toilet tank) at bottom end of the red pipe ... extend the top end of the red pipe to the bottom of the top barrel ... the bottom fills by siphoning action from the top barrel when the top barrel becomes full

Comment: Thanks @jsotola, that also sounds great. Now I'm not sure which solution is better, but it seems like your suggestion would involve less modifications to my current configuration.

Comment: Does it really matter if water is drawn out of the bottom barrels which then refill from the ones instead of drawing from the top ones and only from the bottom when the top are empty? Honest question, I don't know. Seems to me that drawing from the bottom ones prevents the water from sitting stagnant for too long, potentially growing things in there.

Comment: @FreeMan I put 8 of these all linked in series for rainwater so my parents can water the garden... There is enough rain and use that stagnant is not an issue, so it might depend on the OP's planned use.

Comment: Fair enough. As I said, honest question that I didn't know the answer to. Guess it depends on rain rate and use rate. I'd still think, though, that leaving the bottom tanks to be used only once the top tanks are empty _could_ leave the water sitting in them for a while. Again - up to the OP to determine his/her use rate and tolerance for stagnant water. It's something that (obviously) caught my attention and it's something for OP to think about.

Comment: @FreeMan if worried you could put a shutoff valve on the outlet from the upper tanks and then choose which to use... 1/2 from top then 1/2 from bottom ...

Comment: @FreeMan, thanks for bringing this up :) This is something that I did not consider. My intended use is automatic lawn watering. One of the bottom barrels is connected to a water pump that will start automatically every day (or every second day). Because the total capacity of the system is not too big (120 L x 4, garden is also not big), I didn't even consider water stagnation issues.. yet

Comment: Glad I could help @JuanCortines. Again, I'm not familiar with the systems, it was just a question that popped into my head.

Comment: I used brass tank connectors for all the connections, a much better seal. See this for an example : https://www.screwfix.com/p/compression-tank-connector-22mm/36982

Comment: Turned out I have a small problem after the modifications. When the upper barrels are empty, but there is still water on the lower barrels, the pump connected to the outlet is not capable of using the remaining water, because air from the upper barrels is suck in instead. Any idea how I could solve this? Thanks

Comment: Make sure the outlet is below the water level in the lower barrels otherwise it will suck air...

Comment: It's lower. I think the problem is the pump is able to "suck" faster than what the lower barrels (and the connection) can provide, which means it will try to suck water from the upper barrels as well, taking in some air instead.

Comment: You can put another oneway valve above the pump outlet point as long as the valve ball floats. So when there is water above it will rise and let the water through, if no water then the suction will drag the valve shut. But if the pump suction head is too much it will close the valve.

Comment: Thank again for the suggestion but I'm not sure if I get it. I'm assuming the new oneway valve would be connected between the upper barrels and the outlet's 3-way connector (similar as the other oneway valve). My understanding is that the oneway valve will let water and air to be suck towards the outlet, so I'm not sure how this would help...

Comment: The second oneway valve is in the **same** direction as the first... You could make it such that the ball rises to the level of water in the lower tanks then it probably won't be caught by the pump suction head...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109332/discussion-between-juan-cortines-and-solar-mike).

Comment: @JuanCortines see my edit, and sorry don't have time for a chat - kids need feeding and the suggestion is clear.

Comment: Ok, I guess what you are suggesting in to connect the second oneway valve upside down, and that will let water from the upper barrels flow towards the outlet but not the air. This is for me quite counter-intuitive :) A oneway valve should not avoid precisely that? Thanks

Comment: Well, thanks for the edit. It's very well explained. I'll give it a shot and see how it goes :)

Comment: @jsotola, would your solution also involve joining lower and upper outputs at the outlet? I'm asking this question because the current solution (this post) involves some additional complications when connecting a pump at the output (air sucking). The solution offered by FreeMan works fine but you need an additional Ball Check Valve that will close by gravity at the absence of water, as to block air flow intake to the pump and create vacuum.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I've drawn an alternate configuration based on the solution originally proposed by @jsotola. I don't know if it's the optimal solution, but I think it fixes a potential problem with lack of vacuum when connection a pump to the outlet. I apologise if does not directly answer the question, but I think it solves the main underlying problem. Either way I think it's worth to leave this answer here for posterity, although I will not mark it as the answer unless it gets upvoted by other users. Thanks!
[image]

**Update**
The float valve is still the best solution I've found so far. However float valves are quite slow, which cause two problems:

1. While using the water, it's possible the lower barrels get empty
   while the upper ones still have water. This is not a big problem for
   me because I use the water every 1 or 2 days in small doses.
2. While filling the barrels, it's possible the upper barrels get full
   while the lower ones are not full yet. Easy solution is to connect
   the upper barrel overflow directly to the lower barrel, adding a new
   overflow to the lower barrel.

**Update**
I'm considering to replace the float valve with a float switch + actuated ball valve. The float valves I tried to far are painfully slow.

Answer (score 0):

If reconfiguring the barrels, as suggested by others, isn't an option I would try two things:

1) **Teflon Tape.** In the past, I've used Teflon tape on a smaller diameter/volume container but similar working head pressure and it worked well. The lid must be fairly rigid or it would deflect around rather than compress the tape. As a result I had to use A LOT of tape. Likely one roll per barrel in your application. I eventually learned to replace the Teflon tape every time I opened the container and replace the lid every 10-12 times I opened it due to the plastic deforming.

2) **Gluing.** More permanent but more reliable. Obviously only for consideration if you don't want access to the interior ever again. I'm assuming these are standard polyethylene drums. PE is very hard to glue due to it's chemical properties, however there are some glues on the market which "activate" the surface to prepare it for bonding. [Here](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Loctite-Plastics-Bonding-System-2g-Super-Glue-681925/100371829) is a brand available at my local hardware store.

Comment: Hi Andrew and thanks for the suggestion. I need to have the ability to clean them from time to time, so rather not gluing. I think I'll try the teflon tape if there is no better alternative..