# Will water tank pressure vary by tank platform height?

Tags: plumbing, water, pipe, water-pressure

We have a water tank (1000 liters) in our slab with extra 5 feet height and want to connect another tank of same quantity in slab(no extra height), like this:

```
Water pump input > tank1 > tank2 > output
```

Will the pressure change in output or will it be the same as the original tank?

Comment: Water eill fro from the highest tank into the lowest tank unless you do something about it. **Basic** rule is water will find its own level.

Comment: Consider my answer here: https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/193798/97780

Comment: If the water is pressurized by the pump, it will go uphill, and it should come out the end of a 2-tank system the same way it comes out of a 1-tank system, presuming that all the piping is of the same diameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If tank2 was open to the atmosphere and there was an open line connecting tank1 to tank2, then the contents of tank1 would flow without limit into the tank2 leading to overflow.

If tank2 were sealed off from the atmosphere, then tank2 would be pressurized at the level of tank1.

If tank2 was sealed from the atmosphere, to allow tank2 to fill you would need a valve on top to bleed air until full and then you would close the valve.

EDIT
You could have tank2 open to the atmosphere if you would have a "riser" tube that goes up above the top of tank1. In that case the pressure in tank1 would be the same as tank1.